# aggregate function, newest date

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a table

```
date    name
2014-01-01  AAA
2014-01-01  BBB
2014-01-01  CCC
2014-01-01  DDD
2015-05-05  AAA
2016-09-09  AAA
2016-09-09  BBB
```

and I want to have only the newest information about every person:

```
date    name
2016-09-09  AAA
2016-09-09  BBB
2014-01-01  CCC
2014-01-01  DDD
```

I can simply write

```
SELECT MAX(date), name
FROM table1
GROUP BY name;
```

but if I want to add another column, it doesn't work

```
SELECT MAX(date), name, address
FROM table1
GROUP BY name;
```

(doesn't work)

```
SELECT MAX(date), name, address
FROM table1
GROUP BY name, address;
```

(it works, but I want to have only one record for one person)

How can I do it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your dates for each name are unique, it's quite simple to solve using a derived table and join, like this:

```
SELECT maxdate, t.name, t.address
from table1 t
inner join
(
    SELECT MAX(date) as maxdate, name
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY name
) d on(t.date = d.maxdate and t.name = d.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL-Server* you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in following:

```
SELECT [date], name, address
FROM (
       SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, address ORDER BY [date] DESC) rn
       FROM Table1
     )x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `table1` group by name order by name, date
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT MAX(date), distinct name
FROM table1
GROUP BY name;
```

may be this will work .

Comment: Syntax error. DISTINCT belongs to the SELECT, i.e. it's SELECT DISTINCT. And DISTINCT applies to the whole selected rows, not just one column. (And not needed when group by like this, since the result contains no duplicate rows.)